# Zorder in JTextPane

Tags: paint, jtextpane, z-order

I have JTextPane with implemented resizing of image in it. I made it by declare my own IconView and my own EditorKit which is using this IconView. Every time when user change size of picture, I'm calling JTextPane method paintAll().

Before and after changing size is everything all right. But during dragging the picture I want to have picture in the front.

Before dragging (correct)

[image: Before dragging]

During dragging first picture (**bad Zorder**)

[image]

After dragging (correct)

[image]

During dragging second picture (correct because second picture is painted after first picture)

[image]

I understand that it is caused by order of components in JTextPane, but I don't know how to order to JTextPane to paint this picture as the last one. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible ways. First of all you should ignore view's paint during drag process. Then either

1. Create a JWindow without border but just with one image. Resize to the window and after drag end just get the window's sizes and apply it back to the image.
2. Override paintComponent() of the JTextPane and keep draggedPicture reference. During drag skip the dragged view's paint but instead resize and paint (after calling super) the dragged image in the paintComponent()
3. Keep the dragged rectangle and exclude it from clip of Graphics in the paint() method of all the not dragged views. Like this

---

```
Shape oldCliep=g.getClip();
Area newClip=new Area(oldClip);
newClip.subtract(draggedImageBoundRect);
g.setClip(newClip);
//do all your paint e.g. super.paint() and restore clip
g.setClip(oldClip);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for comprehensive answer. First solution seems to be best way for me, because I have some other issues with resizing. I hope, in separate window will be everything ok. I need some time for implementation of this. I let you know if it works.